# node-gyp not not getting rebuild

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm

I am trying to run the following command,
`node-gyp rebuild --arch=arm64`

```
` node-gyp rebuild --arch=arm64 
  gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
  gyp info using node-gyp@9.4.0
  gyp info using node@14.21.3 | darwin | arm64
  gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.0 found at    
  "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3"`
```

My node version: 14.21.3

Can some one help me whats wrong with it? I been trying a lot but not able to find the right solution.

I need to find a solution to resolve the error I am seeing in the terminal